# Where is my app's .pch file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, stackmob

I am following a tutorial on how to set up an iPhone app project in StackMob. This is the instruction:

"Somewhere in your project, such as your project's .pch file, import the SystemConfiguration and MobileCoreServices frameworks."

StackMob provides a set of foundational files, a kind of sample app. Where in these files should I look for this .pch file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just search for it in Xcode's GUI:
[image]